# Making an assert statement in comments

Tags: pycharm

PyCharm does not know how to infer types from the code you type in unless its all pure python. So, I wanted to ask, is there any way to let the code sniffer know this:

```
assert isinstance(object, str)
```

In the comments, instead of actually writing it in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a string just after `object` appears:

```
def f():
    object = smth()
    """@type: int"""
    # Now pycharm knows that object is int
```

See http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html for more information.